# Only send form (get) data if field is fulfilled (not validation)

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a form, that is this one

```
<form method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
   <input name="date-beginning" type="text" class="datepicker" />
   <input name="date-end" type="text" class="datepicker" />
   <input name="s" type="text" />
   <input type="submit" value="Ok" class="botao-pequeno botao-pequeno-input" />
</form>
```

Well, when the user sends all the fields, we get this response:
http://myblogurl.com/?s=example&date-beginning=05/05/05&date-end=07/07/07

If he doesn't fill, for example the `date-beginning` field we get http://myblogurl.com/?s=example&date-beginning=&date-end=07/07/07

What I want is that if he doesn't fill the field, for example `date-beginning`, the form still be sent, but variable don't to get sent, like this: http://myblogurl.com/?s=example&date-end=07/07/07

Is there a way to do it? How?

Comment: No, there is no simple task for this, but check this out: http://www.servicenowguru.com/scripting/business-rules-scripting/hide-empty-variables-standard-form/

Comment: This *is* still validation. It is just that instead of preventing the form submission you are removing the form item and then submitting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var form = document.forms[0];
form.addEventListener('submit', function(){
    var a = document.getElementsByName('date-beginning')[0];
    if(a.value === '')
        a.disabled = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

karaxuna's anwser works. I just adapted it to jQuery, if any one is interested, this is the code

```
$("#the-form").submit(function() {
        if($('#the-field').val() === ''){
            $('#the-field').attr('disabled',true);
        }
        if($('#the-other-field').val() === ''){
            $('#the-other-field').attr('disabled',true);
        }
    });
```